# Expecting a vector value and getting an array instead for a reg

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I am trying to create Verilog code which allows for an LED to blink at a certain frequency. I have a `reg` that I am using as a counter that I think should be a vector but is instead saying it's a packed array in ModelSim.

**VERILOG CODE**

```
module main(
    input wire clk,         //100MHz//
    input wire reset_,
    output LED1     //LED On/Off Two-States//
    );
    reg [27:0] LEDStateCount;   //LED Counter - 27 Bit Stored//
    reg OFF;            //State of LED//    
    localparam [27:0] Freq=50000000;    
    assign LED1 = OFF;         
    always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_)begin
        if (!reset_)begin
            LEDStateCount <= 28'b0;    //On startup, clear value//
            OFF <= 1'b1;
        end
        else if (LEDStateCount<Freq)begin
            LEDStateCount <= LEDStateCount + 1'b1;    //Accumulate to ~50,000,000//
        end 
    else if (LEDStateCount == Freq); begin
        OFF <= 1'b0;             //LED Off Until Value Reached//
        end
    end
endmodule
```

**TEST BENCH**

```
`timescale 1 ps/ 1 ps
module testbenchsaveme();
reg clk;
reg reset_;                                             
wire LED1;                              
main i1 (   
    .LED1(LED1),
    .clk(clk),
    .reset_(reset_)
);
initial 
begin 
#100000000 $stop;
end 
always
begin
    clk = 1'b0;
    clk = #5000 1'b1;
    #5000;
end  
initial
begin
    reset_ = 1'b1;
    reset_ = #100 1'b0;
end 
endmodule
```

[image: ModelSim Waveform]

A few things I am confused about.

1. Shouldn't my `OFF`  Signal be set to 1 in this scenario after the `!reset_`? Originally I had this my `OFF` set to 1'b0 in that reset_ loop, but that gave me a value of 1 after the negedge of `reset_`.
2. I believe LEDStateCount should be vector that is 28 bits long in binary; however ModelSim seems to be treating them as 28x1 array. Regardless of how it's being stored, I thought it should still increment in situations where the LEDStateCount is not equal to the stored Freq value.
3. If I don't set it to increment by a bit value and instead use `1`, my `OFF` signal never initializes and I'm not sure why that is.

I'm not sure if these issues are because of a lack of experience in ModelSim, an issue with the code, or a bit of both. The `clk` is operating as expected and, when forced as a value, I can get `LED1` to produce the signal I am looking for, that being high or low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem was a tricky one.  You have a semicolon where you don't want it to be.  Change:

```
else if (LEDStateCount == Freq); begin
```

to:

```
else if (LEDStateCount == Freq) begin
```

Now I see `OFF` become 1.

---

The second problem regarding your counter not counting is due to the reset signal.  Since your reset signal is active-low, you want to drive it differently in your testbench:

```
initial
begin
    reset_ = 1'b0;
    reset_ = #100 1'b1;
end
```

Normally, you want the reset to be asserted at time 0, then released after a delay.  In your code, you assert it at time 100, then keep it asserted for the duration of the sim.  This prevents the counter from incrementing.